# creating function of Telegram inline keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, telegram, inline, telegram-bot

I need to write a function that creates an inline-keyboard. The function parameter is an integer, for example **i**.

Number of buttons in the keyboard: **i** + 1.
Condition number of buttons per line: <=3.

Comment: Okay, good luck!

Comment: Please ask an actual question. Show the code that you have written, where your problem occurs. What exactly is holding you back?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer and since you mentioned aiogram in your comment, there's already a feature implemented inside the library for your use case:

```py
# number_of_buttons_in_row would be 3 in your case
def get_kb(number_of_buttons, number_of_buttons_in_row):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()    
    markup.row_width = number_of_buttons_in_row     # key part is here

    for i in range(1, number_of_buttons):
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i), callback_data='button_' + str(i ** i)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i + 1), callback_data='button_' + str(i ** i + 1)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i + 2), callback_data='button ' + str(i ** i + 2)))

    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q), callback_data='button ' + str(q)),
               InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))

    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q-1), callback_data='button ' + str(q-1)),
               InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q), callback_data='button ' + str(q)),
               InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))
    return markup
```

As you can see there's a field called `row_width` inside markup, that's used to slice the buttons into the given width and place them in several lines

Comment: I am using  InlineKeyboardMarkup and InlineKeyboardButton from aiogram. When I use your code, I lost button **number_of_buttons_in_row+1**. But if I change line 7 for             `row_buttons = [{"text": "Button " + str(i), "callback_data": "data_" + str(i)}]`                            it don't happen

Comment: You didn't mention aiogram in your question, please always include as many details as you can to get better answers. I update my answer with the new code, since aiogram itself had my previous written algorithm, you don't need to write another algorithm for that. Just use the `markup.row_width` and add your buttons, it will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I found this variant:

```
def get_kb(number_of_buttons):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    lines = int(number_of_buttons/3)+1
    last_lines = (number_of_buttons % 3)
    for i in range(1, lines):
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i), callback_data='button_' + str(i ** i)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i + 1), callback_data='button_' + str(i ** i + 1)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(i ** i + 2), callback_data='button ' + str(i ** i + 2)))
    if last_lines == 0:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))
    elif last_lines == 1:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q), callback_data='button ' + str(q)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))
    else:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q-1), callback_data='button ' + str(q-1)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('button ' + str(q), callback_data='button ' + str(q)),
                   InlineKeyboardButton('others', callback_data='others'))
```

But I think that isn't the best variant